# Question about the global approximation Theorem of Evans

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

I'm reading the theorem of global approximation of Evans and I'm wondering why taking $\varepsilon>0$ small we can say that $B(x^{\epsilon},\epsilon)$ lies in $U\cap B(x^0,r)$
[image]
[image]

---

**My proof**
(Observation, I'm denoting the ball centered in $x$ with radius $r>0$ like $U_r(x)$)

Let $x \in V$. Since $V$ is an open set, there exists an $s > 0$ such that $U_s(x) \subset V$. Take $\lambda \in (0, \frac{r}{s})$ fixed, and observe that
\begin{align*}
    ||x^{\epsilon} - x^0|| &= ||x - \lambda \epsilon e_{N} - x^0|| \\
    &\leq ||x - x^0|| + \lambda \epsilon < \frac{r}{2} + \left(\frac{r}{s}\right)\left(\frac{s}{2}\right) = r,
\end{align*}

for $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\epsilon < \frac{s}{2}$. Thus, we obtain $x^{\epsilon} \in U_r(x^0)$.

Now, note that $(x^{\epsilon})_N = x_N + \lambda \epsilon > x_N > \gamma(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{N-1}) = \gamma(x_1^{\epsilon}, x_2^{\epsilon}, \ldots, x_{N-1}^{\epsilon})$. Therefore, $x^{\epsilon} \in U \cap U_r(x^0)$ for all $\epsilon < \frac{s}{2}$.

As $x^{\epsilon} \to x$, there exists a $\delta := \delta_s > 0$ such that if $\epsilon < \delta$, then $||x^{\epsilon} - x|| < \frac{s}{2}$.

With the two previous observations, it can be shown that for $\epsilon < \min\{\frac{s}{2}, \delta\}$, $U_{\epsilon}(x^{\epsilon}) \subset U_s(x)$. Indeed, take $z \in U_{\epsilon}(x^{\epsilon})$, then
\begin{align*}
    ||z - x|| &\leq ||z - x^{\epsilon}|| + ||x^{\epsilon} - x|| < \epsilon + \frac{s}{2} < \frac{s}{2} + \frac{s}{2} = s.
\end{align*}

Hence, we have established $U_{\epsilon}(x^{\epsilon}) \subset U_s(x) \subset V \subset U \cap U_r(x^0)$ for small $\epsilon > 0$.

It is correct?

Comment: I haven’t gone through this in detail, but I’m 95% sure there’s a flaw in here somewhere (probably with the order of dependencies). The large enough $\lambda$ is obtained by considering the (local) Lipschitz constant of the function $\gamma$ which (locally) defines the boundary. In your proof, you never invoked anything about Lipschitzness of $\gamma$, so I’m highly suspicious.